# MercadoPago en Swift como instalar

Tags: swift, mercadopago

Hola  soy nuevo con programación y me gustaría saber como puedo instalar el SDK en un proyecto de Xcode en el que estoy trabajando de integrar Woocommerce

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! a que te referis? que problema especifico tuviste instalando esto?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Según la documentación del sitio, para swift solo hay checkout pro.